# Can Postgres user roles be configured with a default database and/or default schema (other than the "out-of-the-box" default)?

Tags: postgresql

According to the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html) the `dbname` connection parameter defaults to the user name:

> `dbname`
>
> The database name. Defaults to be the same as the user name.
>   In certain contexts, the value is checked for extended formats;
>   see Section 31.1.1 for more details on those.

My first question is: what happens if there is no database that corresponds to the user name - and is there a way to define a default other than the database that has the same name as the user name? (How can this be achieved?)

My seconds question is: once connected to a database can a default schema be defined for the user? (How can this be achieved?)

Comment: `alter role set search_path = ...`

Answer (score 0):

Users cannot be set with a default database, because the decision of which database to connect to is a client-side one made before the server is first connected to.

It's not the PostgreSQL server with that default, it's `libpq` and the client tools like `psql`. Those tools examine the `PGDATABASE` environment variable, so you can set that, but you have no control over the behaviour from server-side.

You *can* set a default for the schema search path, as @a_horse_with_no_name notes, with

```
ALTER ROLE rolename SET search_path = ....
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Right, because it's an identifier-list. Thanks for the correction.